# PermissionError when moving image after being opened in Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a small script for tallying pagecounts in multi-page TIFFs before moving them to another drive; but whether or not I explicitly close the images after opening them with Pillow, I keep getting a PermissionError when subsequently trying to move the file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 522, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:/users/barry/desktop/bort.tiff' ->  'c:/users/barry/desktop/bart.tiff'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#75>", line 1, in <module>
    shutil.move('c:/users/barry/desktop/bort.tiff', 'c:/users/barry/desktop/bart.tiff')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\shutil.py", line 535, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:/users/barry/desktop/bort.tiff'
```

I've tried each of the following methods, plus other variations I've already forgotten:

```
import os
import shutil
from PIL import Image

name1 = 'C:/Users/Barry/Desktop/bort.tiff' # This file exists.
name2 = 'C:/Users/Barry/Desktop/bart.tiff' # This file doesn't.

# Attempt 1:
img = Image.open(name1)
pgs = img.n_frames
img.close()               # Tried both with and without this in each attempt.
shutil.move(name1, name2) # Tried both shutil.move and os.rename

# Attempt 2:
with Image.open(name1) as img:
    pgs = img.n_frames
    img.close()           
shutil.move(name1, name2)

# Attempt 3:
with Image.open(name1) as img:
    pgs = img.n_frames
img.close()               
shutil.move(name1, name2) 

# Attempt 4:
with open(name1, 'rb') as file:
    with Image.open(file) as img:
        pgs = img.n_frames
img.close()               
shutil.move(name1, name2)
```

Even containing each distinct operation in different functions made no difference.

Where am I going wrong?

I'm using Pillow v3.0.0 with Python v3.4.2 on both Win7 and Win10.

Answer (score -1):

What you are facing over here is [Sharing Violation Error](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2011-August/011738.html)

to avoid that you should use Win32file.movefile for further information you should [go to](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEYQFjAHahUKEwiM_fDr0_3IAhVHk3IKHY4NBrM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fwindows%2Fdesktop%2Faa365239(v%3Dvs.85).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFzN2v3_4rAKs7M37jkzjGqAuZrPw&sig2=k24rYo93ne19Lm2_1Ub-Fw&bvm=bv.106923889,d.d24)

```
win32file.MoveFile(source, target)
```

will do the work.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me figure out how or from where to get win32file. But unfortunately, this script will also have to be Linux compatible.

Comment: [This is](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) where you'll find Win32file also you can find an [exe](http://starship.python.net/~skippy/downloads/win32all-163.exe) from here, and yes script will remain Linux compatible use platform module and then apply your code according to platform architecture. Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, that didn't work:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>

    win32file.MoveFile('c:/users/barry/desktop/bort.tiff', 'd:/bart.tiff')

pywintypes.error: (32, 'MoveFile', 'The process cannot access the file 

because it is being used by another process.')

Comment: This looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116422/unable-to-delete-file-file-being-used-by-another-process.